# opencl does not detect CPU

Tags: opencl, gpu, cpu, intel, nvidia

Finally I installed new nvidia-drivers and the AMD SDK APP v3.0 but its only detecting my GPU.

I installed the AMD SDK app in my home-directory.

Do you know what possibly gone wrong?

> CPU: model name   : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz

clinfo:

```
    Number of platforms:                 1
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 8.0.13
  Platform Name:                 NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor:               NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts


  Platform Name:                 NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices:               1
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Vendor ID:                     10deh
  Max compute units:                 1
  Max work items dimensions:             3
    Max work items[0]:               1024
    Max work items[1]:               1024
    Max work items[2]:               64
  Max work group size:               1024
  Preferred vector width char:           1
  Preferred vector width short:          1
  Preferred vector width int:            1
  Preferred vector width long:           1
  Preferred vector width float:          1
  Preferred vector width double:         1
  Native vector width char:          1
  Native vector width short:             1
  Native vector width int:           1
  Native vector width long:          1
  Native vector width float:             1
  Native vector width double:            1
  Max clock frequency:               1480Mhz
  Address bits:                  32
  Max memory allocation:             268353536
  Image support:                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:       128
  Max number of images write arguments:      8
  Max image 2D width:                16384
  Max image 2D height:               16384
  Max image 3D width:                2048
  Max image 3D height:               2048
  Max image 3D depth:                2048
  Max samplers within kernel:            16
  Max size of kernel argument:           4352
  Alignment (bits) of base address:      4096
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                     Yes
    Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:           Yes
    Round to zero:               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
  Cache type:                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:               128
  Cache size:                    16384
  Global memory size:                1073414144
  Constant buffer size:              65536
  Max number of constant args:           9
  Local memory type:                 Scratchpad
  Local memory size:                 49152
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     32
  Error correction support:          0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:        0
  Profiling timer resolution:            1000
  Device endianess:              Little
  Available:                     Yes
  Compiler available:                Yes
  Execution capabilities:                
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:             No
  Queue on Host properties:              
    Out-of-Order:                Yes
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Platform ID:                   0x8d3ee00
  Name:                      GeForce GT 520M
  Vendor:                    NVIDIA Corporation
  Device OpenCL C version:           OpenCL C 1.1 
  Driver version:                361.28
  Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                   OpenCL 1.1 CUDA
  Extensions:                    cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts
```

Comment: Doesnt intel need its special drivers for opencl(for any implementation to recognize it as a device)? Are you querying with CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL ?

Comment: Thank you! I installed the Intel drivers for Opencl! Its working now

Comment: Does it detect Intel® HD Graphics 3000 or did intel totally cut that off of opencl?

Comment: No, it does not detect Intel HD Graphics.. Only CPU and my nvidia-gpu

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Integrated GPU is turned off for some motherboards when a discrete GPU is found.